# Help with desert garden plant identification

Tags: identification, cactus, desert

I recently purchased a property in southern NM. Previous owner was an avid gardener that let it go in recent years (maybe decades?) so it's going to take a lot of work to look nice again. I am not very knowledgeable about gardening or plants, but I do want to preserve and care for the ones that are still alive after having been neglected for such a long time. Problem is, I don't know what any of these are.

[image: First Plant]
This guy seems to have some edible fruit on it. I thought it might be something like a dragon fruit, but it doesn't quite match. Is it edible?

[image: Second Plant]
I *think* this is a yucca plant, but it looks more like a tree, and I thought those were bushes, so maybe not?

[image: Third Plant]
I thought this might be a prickly pear, but it doesn't seem to have the right shape.

[image: Fourth Plant]
No idea what this is, other than it's a cactus.

[image: Fifth Plant]
Same with this one.

Could anyone identify/ confirm what these are? Thanks!

Comment: I believe they want one plant per question.  Not sure without input from the closers though.

Comment: Jeremy, welcome! What an exciting project you are tackling here. I’m sorry to close your first question, but this site has a very clear rule about identification questions: one plant per post. (As you have been around the network, you’ll realize how this would collide with the voting system and the usefulness for future users.) Easy remedy: ask _multiple_ questions, get dedicated answers and more upvotes ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first image is a Cholla cactus. The yellow fruits are edible and so are the flower buds.

The second does look like a yucca plant, possibly yucca rigida based on the morphology and SW America region: https://southwestdesertflora.com/WebsiteFolders/All_Species/Agavaceae/Yucca%20rigida,%20Blue%20Yucca.html

The third definitely looks like some kind of opuntia (prickly pear), perhaps Opuntia Laevis

The fourth and fifth look like more Chollas, the fifth being a younger individual.